# How to transfer data between panels of cardLayout

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

In my software I am using card layout to create a "wizard-based" interface. In panel, user chooses a file, in the other one get information regarding the chosen file in previous panel.

The problem is that CardLayout loads all panels all together. So panels deals with predefined data. But I would like to update the next panel with the information given in the current panel.
each panel has 'next' and 'back' buttons, so I think that is the point where next panels can get updated somehow. I thought using setters and getters methods but could not implement it correctly.

Here is a sample code with two sub-panels:
BASE CLASS:

```
   public Base(){
            frame.setLayout(bl);
            frame.setSize(800, 600);
            frame.add(new MainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here
            new Base();
        }
    }
```

MainPanel (sub-panels holder)

```
class MainPanel extends JPanel{
    private CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
    private JPanel panelHolder = new JPanel(cl);

    public MainPanel() {
        ChooseFile chooseFile = new ChooseFile(this);
        ShowResult showResult = new ShowResult(this);

        panelHolder.add(showResult, "showResult");
        panelHolder.add(chooseFile, "chooseFile");

        cl.show(panelHolder, "chooseFile");
        add(panelHolder);
    }
    public void showPanel(String panelIdentifier){
        cl.show(panelHolder, panelIdentifier);
    }
}
```

Sub-Panel 1:

```
class ChooseFile extends JPanel{
    MainPanel ob2;
    JPanel directoryChooserPanel, bottomPanel;
    JButton btn, localSourceBack, localSourceNext;
    JTextField field;
    public ChooseFile(MainPanel mainPanel){
        this.ob2 = mainPanel;
        ShowResult showResult = new ShowResult();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        directoryChooserPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2));
        btn = new JButton("Browse");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("D:\\Desktop");
                chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                    File myFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                    String text = myFile + "";

                    field.setText(text); 
                }
            }
        });


        directoryChooserPanel.add(btn);

        field = new JTextField(20);
        directoryChooserPanel.add(field);



        localSourceNext = new JButton("Next");
        localSourceNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                ob2.showPanel("showResult");
                showResult.setRoot(getPath());
            }
        });

        add(directoryChooserPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(localSourceNext, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }
    public String getPath(){
        return field.getText();
    }
}
```

Sub Panel 2:

```
class ShowResult extends JPanel{
    MainPanel ob2;
    JPanel bottomPanel, labelsPanel;
    JButton srcLocalBTN, srcFtpBTN, sourceLocationBack;
    JLabel result;
    File directory;
    String root;
    ArrayList<String> myFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ShowResult(MainPanel mainPanel){
        this.ob2 = mainPanel;
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        result = new JLabel();
        root = "No ADDRESS";
        directory = new File(root);

        listFiles(directory, myFiles);
        String filesNumber = "It contains " + myFiles.size() + " files.";
        result.setText(filesNumber);

        add(result, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    public void listFiles(File directory, ArrayList<String> list){
            for(File file : directory.listFiles()){
                list.add(file.getName());
                if(file.isDirectory()){
                    listFiles(file.getAbsoluteFile(), list);
                }
            }
    }
    public ShowResult(){

    }
    public void setRoot(String chosenPath){
        root = chosenPath;
    }
}
```

So it firsts loads 'sub panel 1' so user chooses a directory by `jFileChooser` and then I need to transfer this data to 'sub panel 2'. So it can calculate how many files it is containing.
I tried to transfer data by getting the chosen directory and assigning to a variable in the second variable. But doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating more than one ShowResult object, displaying one but then passing information to the other, the non-displayed one, but this is not how Java works (this is easy to discover by simply searching this page for number of `new ShowResult()` matches).  You need to be sure that the ShowResult object that is displayed is the exact same as the one you pass information to, meaning you'll have to pass the reference of the displayed object into your ChooseFile class via a constructor or method parameter.

Better option: use an MVC design pattern, make, have your controls change the state of the model and your views display the state of your model. This may reduce the cyclomatic complexity of your code.

Comment: Thanks. You are right.I didn't think about the fact that there are 2 objects of one class. However, Can you please provide a sample code, or links regarding MVC tutorial. I have read about it but do know how to implement it in my software.

Comment: What i am asking myself is, if a `CardLayout` suited for what you want to achieve. I have no idea. If i read the JavaDoc about what CardLayout is supposed to do... Looking at this answer i suspect it could, or maybe that is not concidered in this answer.

Comment: @Dan: that would require that I write a book chapter. Google MVC tutorial for many links. Also you can look at what I've written on it before, including some code examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A522444+%5Bswing%5D+mvc).

Comment: Well having a little version of MVC of my code would make it easier to understand. However the theory, I must have a model that does the calculation, and 2 views, which one gets data from one panel and another one that sets result to another panel. And a controller that triggers when the _next_ button is pressed and link views to model. Is it the right idea?

Comment: @Dan: `"Well having a little version of MVC of my code would make it easier to understand."` -- absolutely, but my work and time constraints prevent me from doing this as it would be asking a major effort on my part.

Comment: `"However the theory, I must have a model that does the calculation, and 2 views, which one gets data from one panel and another one that sets result to another panel. And a controller that triggers when the next button is pressed and link views to model. Is it the right idea?"` -- sounds pretty good to me.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I appreciate the fact that you mentioned to key points. It was enough for me to find out about MVC and solve my problem. Thanks again.